# java.lang.NullPointerException output term frequency-inverse document frequency (tfidf) matrix java

Tags: java, file, matrix, hashmap, tf-idf

I have this code that outputs the tfidf for all words in each file in the directory. I'm trying  to transfer this to a matrix where each row correspond to each file in the directory and each column to all words in the files and I have some difficulty in doing it and i need some help.
what i get is a java.lang.NullPointerException when i try to output the matrix. 
The values start to appear but for some reason they stop and the null error generates.

this is the code

```
public class TestTF_IDF {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException{
    //Test code for TfIdf
    TfIdf tf = new TfIdf("E:/Thesis/ThesisWork/data1");
    //Contains file name being processed
    //String file;


    tf.buildAllDocuments();


    int numDocuments = tf.documents.size();
    Double matrix[][] = new Double[numDocuments][];

    int documentIndex = 0;
    for (String file : tf.documents.keySet())
    {
       // System.out.println("File \t" + file);

        Map<String, Double[]> myMap = 
            tf.documents.get(file).getF_TF_TFIDF();

        int numWords = myMap.size();
        matrix[documentIndex] = new Double[numWords];

        int wordIndex = 0;
        for (String key : myMap.keySet())
        {
            Double[] values = myMap.get(key);
            matrix[documentIndex][wordIndex] = values[2];
            wordIndex++;
             //System.out.print("file="+ file+ "term=" +key + values[2]+" ");
        }
        documentIndex++;


        for(int i=0; i<numDocuments;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<numWords;j++){

           System.out.print("file="+ file+ matrix[i][j]+ " ");  //error here
            }
        }
    }

}//public static void main(String[] args)
 }//public class TestTF_IDF
```

Any ideas. Thanks

Comment: What does `tf.documents` contain? Particularly, what are the `Double[]` arrays? (Are these 1-element arrays that contain the frequencies?)

Comment: @Marco13 documents is a TreeMap (TreeMap<String, Document> documents) that contains the documents declared in TFIdf class and tf is an object of that class ( see line 5) and about the arrays just ignore the dfIdf array it is not used anymore and about values array is the one that holds the values of myMay.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that creating this matrix is easy. But not as long as it is not clear which data you have (in which structure), and what of this data should be contained in the matrix. So `tf.documents` maps a file name to a `Document`? And `getF_TF_TFIDF` returns a map that maps ... words? to ... what?

Comment: could you please tell me what i wrote for outputing the matrix is correct or no.. thank you

Comment: Please, close your eyes for a moment, and imagine you are someone else. Then open your eyes, read the question and the code, and try to imagine: *What could be an answer to this question?*. Nobody knows your data structures, what they contain, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: You have to move the last 2 `for`-loops (where you are trying to print the matrix) one level "deeper". That is, do this *after* the `for (String file : tf.documents.keySet()) { ... }` loop....

Comment: It did not work.. Still have errors. Thanks

Comment: You should definitely read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . But we're discussing alrady, anyhow. So what kind of error?

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is remarkably unclear, here is what I tried to guess based on the question and the comments.

```
import java.util.Map;

public class TestTF_IDF
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        TfIdf tf = new TfIdf("E:/Thesis/ThesisWork/data1");
        tf.buildAllDocuments();

        int numDocuments = tf.documents.size();
        Double[] matrix[][] = new Double[numDocuments][][];

        int documentIndex = 0;
        for (String file : tf.documents.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println("File \t" + file);

            Map<String, Double[]> myMap = 
                tf.documents.get(file).getF_TF_TFIDF();

            int numWords = myMap.size();
            matrix[documentIndex] = new Double[numWords][];

            int wordIndex = 0;
            for (String key : myMap.keySet())
            {
                Double[] values = myMap.get(key);
                matrix[documentIndex][wordIndex] = values;
                wordIndex++;
            }
            documentIndex++;
        }
    }
} 


class Document
{
    public Map<String, Double[]> getF_TF_TFIDF()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class TfIdf
{
    public Map<String, Document> documents;
    TfIdf(String s)
    {
    }
    public void buildAllDocuments()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marco 13.. Now I have something to fix and start with. I added your code and I printed the matrix, It starts to output the values of some words of the first file and then a java.lang.NullPointerException appears.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your original question and provide more information about the exception.